# In which situations does a managed object context have changes?

Tags: iphone, core-data

In which situations does a managed object context have changes?

What can happen that -hasChanges returns YES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities: you inserted a new entity, you deleted an entity, you modified an entity(either an attribute or a relation).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by observing NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notifications

[NSManagedObjectContext notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-237802)